# Apple USB Keyboard not working on 27" iMac (Intel Core i7)

Tags: keyboard, imac, usb

I have two similar iMacs (27" - i7 - os10.8.4 ) and use Apple's extended USB keyboards on both of them. After a power outage neither keyboard will work on one iMac (A) although both keyboards work fine on the other iMac (B). I have reset NVRAM and SMC on iMac A but to no avail. I have plugged printers into the USB ports and they seem to work fine. As it stands, the only way I can log in on iMac A is by using a Bluetooth keyboard, the USB port however remains "invisible"...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I presume your question is how can you reconnect the keyboards to the USB port on iMac A?

Comment: Yes Dave, that is my issue. Plugged my keyboard(s) into the iMac (A) and it's as if I plugged "nothing" into the USB port, i.e.: the mac does not see it (even checking the USB port status using "About This Mac"/system info)... Strange, as anything else plugged into the same ports does appear, as it should.

Comment: I have the same problem. iMac 27" i5 OS X 10.8.4

Comment: Do other USB ports work?

Comment: What if you connect a powered USB hub to the computer, and the keyboard to the hub?

Comment: I had this same occurrence when power was knocked out in a storm. This was on MBP, and all the USB ports were fried. You might want to check a mouse connected to each port. If the ports are gone, maybe a Bluetooth keyboard? On the MBP, band I suspect the same with the iMac - the USB ports are on the main logic board. It is simply too costly to repair. Do you have warranty service?

Comment: Do you have a Fusion Drive and a USB sound device plugged in? Check this out https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5659615?start=0&amp;tstart=90

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry this isn't really an answer but I can't post a photo in a comment.*

I have a 27" iMac i7 as well, when I connect a Key Board/Mouse and an iPhone via USB in "System Information" I see this:

[image]

What do you see?

Note that the two USB ports are on different busses.  Have you tried both of them?  You mentioned that bluetooth works; do the other USB functions work (Card Reader, iSight Cam)?

Answer (score -1):

I just got a new iMac with OS 10.8.4 (Snow Leopard) I opted for a USB keyboard and the keyboard stopped working twice now upon restarts.

BUT when I plugged in my old Mac keyboard (which is clunky and encased in a clear plastic like tray) it works fine. My new sleek USB keyboard doesn't.

I feel that all of these problems may be the newer keyboards.  The USB plugs even seems wimpier.

Answer (score -2):

This isa recurring problem for me and whilst I once solved it from a site like this, this time I just plugged the damn thing into my macbook air and back to the Imac. Bingo!

GV